# Coverting an appended object into a linked object?

Tags: animation, rigging, linked-data, append, conversion

"Is it possible to convert a previously appended object into a linked object. So as to retain the animation on the appended object after converting or replacing it with the linked proxy version?"

Comment: I'd say it's much easier to append this object into another file, save it, delete it in the main scene and link it from that saved file.

Comment: That would make sense as a pure method to convert an appended rig etc. into a linked version of the rig etc.. However I'm dealing with a scenario what I desire to link the appended object to it's original which it is currently only appended from, This way I can update the rig with the weight painted mesh etc.. Will answer one achieve this?